# CSS: мобильное меню на css со сдвигом

Tags: css, css3, css-animation

Возможно ли реализовать меню без jQuery, только на css как на нативных мобильных приложениях, чтобы закрывалось свайпом влево?

Допустим блок меню `200px`, то можно задать `left: -200px;` и псевдоэлементом `checked` менять значение с `-200px` на `0`. Можно ли тоже самое делать свайпом?